# How to diagnose performance issues with an encrypted procedure without execute and alter permissions?

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

That's the question I got in the interview. And I couldn't say anything more than parameter sniffing. But this is not a method of finding a solution, but one of the possible problems. And I wonder how you can really diagnose such a situation?

Comment: If you can't run the stored procedure, then your options are indeed limited.  If I was asking this question in an interview, then I would probably expect the candidate to mention cached execution plans, or viewing statistics (e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16493/tracking-stored-procedure-usage).  Another option would be setting up a trace (SQL Profiler), although having the rights to do this and NOT execute stored procedures seems a bit artificial?

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed one of those questions to see how you think and what your depth of knowledge is and how you react. Execution plans, and all these options mentioned by Richard really depend on how the environment is set up (ie, permissions). It would be really weird to have permissions for these and you couldn't exec a stored proc. This is one of those questions someone really wants to grind you. Our DBA is like this, but he's realistic. He'll ask someone to hand write a query that's a classic pick out the max or something similar. He'll use real table names, and he'll wait for the query, then type it in to see if it works. If issues arise, he'll hand it over and ask them to fix it. I feel this is a better approach than asking about what I like to call 'edge cases' that you aren't going to see often.

-Nick